# Bluetooth dongle BLED112 on Debian 10 is not working

Tags: linux, bluetooth, debian, bluez, dongle

I just randomly found a Bluegiga BLED112 Bluetooth dongle and I tried to connect it to my Debian 10 laptop as a basic dongle for Bluetooth audio outs.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to solve all the issues I had, starting from the fact that the device is not fully listed once used `lsusb` and just a mere ID number - namely `ID 2458:0001` - pops out and `bluetooth` or `bluez` helps weren't successful either.

This given, I tried to follow several of the guides you can find online, also by running available scripts, but again nothing worked.

So if it's possible, what should I do in order to run such a dongle for the basic use I mentioned above - i.e. just for connecting my stereo speakers to my computer?

Thanks

Comment: Have you used `bluetoothctl show` or `sudo btmgmt info`? Do they provide any more information about the device? Do you get any debug information with `journalctl -u bluetooth` or `service bluetooth status`?

Comment: This seems like a better question for https://superuser.com/.

Comment: I used both ```bluetoothctl show``` and ```sudo btmgmt info``` but both of them don't provide much - either _No default controller available_ or _Index list with 0 items_. Neither debug informations are available using both ```journalctl -u bluetooth``` or ```service bluetooth status``` apart from systemd starters

Answer (score 1):

The BlueGiga BLED112 is not a regular Bluetooth USB dongle. It gives you a virtual com port that can be used to access an API that in turn acts as a BLE device.

It is ment to be used for development of IOT solutions.

Also it does not support Bluetooth Classic, it only supports Bluetooth Low Energy.